# Error in singleton class in java

Tags: java, singleton

```
public class SingletonDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        Singleton service = Singleton.getInstance();
        service.doSomething();
    }
}
```

when I create  singleton object then obtain error  **Singleton can not be  resolved to a type**.

Comment: Where is your Singleton class?

Comment: This code clearly won't work without the `Singleton` type being declared, with a static `getInstance` method and a `doSomething` method...

Comment: I have no knowledge  about singleton class ?

Comment: I presume this was taken from a textbook.  You are missing part of the example. Go back and re-read it!

Comment: I have read it, no missing   David Wallace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you could write it

```
public class SingletonDemo {
    public static void main(String... ignored) {

        Singleton service = Singleton.getInstance();
        service.doSomething();
    }
}

public enum Singleton {
    INSTANCE;

    public static Singleton getInstance() { return INSTANCE; }

    public void doSomething() {
        System.out.println("Singleton.doSomething() called");
    }
}
```